# Iterable view of RDD/Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, legacy

During migration we have to wrap our legacy code and we are looking for way to iterate over all instances of RDD and Dataframe without the need to copy it to one big Array with `collect()`.

Here is an example with a legacy function data expects a `Iterable` over all data.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector,Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.junit.Test
import org.scalatest.junit.AssertionsForJUnit

class SparkLegacy extends AssertionsForJUnit {

  def legacyFunction(data: Iterable[Vector]) {
    data.foreach(println(_))
  }

  @Test def testRDD() {
    // set up
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val data = Array(Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0))
    val RDD: RDD[Vector] = sc.parallelize(data, 2)

    // this is possible, but may create a huge temporary collection
    // I would prefer to pass an Iterable view of the RDD to the legacy function
    legacyFunction(RDD.collect())
  }

  @Test def testDataframe() {
    // set up
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
      (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
      (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
      (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5)))).toDF("label", "features")

    val col = data.col("features")
    // I have no idea how to efficiently call the legacy function
  }

}
```

Comment: Would rdd.toLocalIterator work? Not quite an Iterable, but you could probably make it into an Iterable if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on David Maust comment:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{ Vector, Vectors }
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.junit.Test
import org.scalatest.junit.AssertionsForJUnit

class SparkLegacy extends AssertionsForJUnit {
  // legacy function to call
  def legacyFunction(data: Iterable[Vector]) {
    data.foreach(println(_))
  }  

  // Enrich RDD with Iterable interface
  implicit class RDDIterable[T](rdd: RDD[T]) extends Iterable[T] {
    override def iterator: Iterator[T] = rdd.toLocalIterator
  }

  @Test def testRDD() {
    // set up
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val data = Array(Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0))
    val RDD: RDD[Vector] = sc.parallelize(data, 2)

    // call legacy function with implicit Iterable
    legacyFunction(RDD)
  }

  @Test def testDataframe() {
    // set up
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
      (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
      (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
      (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5)))).toDF("label", "features")

    // convert to RDD
    val RDD = data.select("features").map { case Row(features: Vector) => features }

    // call legacy function with implicit Iterable
    legacyFunction(RDD)
  }

}
```

However I am new to Spark and have no idea how efficient this is and hence would welcome if an expert could approve or improve this answer.